# Null values are not filling

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with null values inside the data. The null value is in the gender column.
When I try to replace it with mode of that column using the code,

```
name    age income  gender  department  grade   performance_score
0   Allen Smith 45.0    NaN NaN Operations  G3  723
1   S Kumar NaN 16000.0 F   Finance G0  520
2   Jack Morgan 32.0    35000.0 M   Finance G2  674
3   Ying Chin   45.0    65000.0 F   Sales   G3  556
4   Dheeraj Patel   30.0    42000.0 F   Operations  G2  711
5   Satyam Sharma   NaN 62000.0 NaN Sales   G3  649
6   James Authur    54.0    NaN F   Operations  G3  53
7   Josh Wills  54.0    52000.0 F   Finance G3  901
8   Leo Duck    23.0    98000.0 M   Sales   G4  709

mod=df['gender'].mode()
df['gender']= df['gender'].fillna(value= mod)

name    age income  gender  department  grade   performance_score
0   Allen Smith 45.0    NaN NaN Operations  G3  723
1   S Kumar NaN 16000.0 F   Finance G0  520
2   Jack Morgan 32.0    35000.0 M   Finance G2  674
3   Ying Chin   45.0    65000.0 F   Sales   G3  556
4   Dheeraj Patel   30.0    42000.0 F   Operations  G2  711
5   Satyam Sharma   NaN 62000.0 NaN Sales   G3  649
6   James Authur    54.0    NaN F   Operations  G3  53
7   Josh Wills  54.0    52000.0 F   Finance G3  901
8   Leo Duck    23.0    98000.0 M   Sales   G4  709
```

the nan values are not filling with the mode. It is showing NaN in the particular column. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
df["gender"] = df["gender"].fillna(df["gender"].mode()[0])
df.head()
```

|  | name | age | income | gender | department | grade | performance_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Allen Smith | 45.0 | nan | F | Operations | G3 | 723.0 |
| 1 | S Kumar | nan | 16000.0 | F | FinanceG0 | 520 | nan |
| 2 | Jack Morgan | 32.0 | 35000.0 | M | Finance | G2 | 674.0 |
| 3 | Ying Chin | 45.0 | 65000.0 | F | Sales | G3 | 556.0 |
| 4 | Dheeraj Patel | 30.0 | 42000.0 | F | Operations | G2 | 711.0 |

The problem here was that `fillna()` takes in a single value, but `df["gender"].mode()` gives a series. So I just used indexing to access that item and passed it inside `fillna()`.